# Move back to a Form from a div to edit the form html Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form that request user data(name) and then when they click the "check" button the form will get replaced by a div and display the name in it.
Then when the user clicks the "edit" button the user gets prompt back to the form but with the previous entered data. I want to know how to display the details back in the form.

```
<html>

<body>
<div id="container"> 
            <h2 id="heading">Query Form</h2>
            <br>
            <div id="formdiv">
                <form id="form" method="POST">
                <div>
                    <label for="name">Name: </label>
                    <input id="name" name="name" type="text">
                </div>
                <br>
                <button id="checkbutton" onclick=submitform()>Check</button>
                <input type="submit" id="formbutton" value="Submit" onclick=validateForm()>    
            </form>           
        </div>
            
        <div id="for_replacement">
        
            <div id="display_replacment" style="display: none;">
                <form>
                
                    <label for="name_submit">Name: </label><span id="name"></span>
                    <span id="display_name"></span><br><br>

                    <input type="submit" id="formbutton" value="Edit" onclick="editform()">
    
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

<script>

function validateForm() {

  var formrefresh = document.getElementById("form");
  function handleForm(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  
  
  var namevalidate =  document.getElementById("name").value;

  if(namevalidate.length == 0) {
    alert("Please Enter Name");
    formrefresh.addEventListener("submit", handleForm);
    return;
  }else {
    form.action = "mailto:mail@gmail.com"
  }
}


function submitform() {

  globalThis.name = document.getElementById("name").value;

  document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = document.getElementById("display_replacment").innerHTML;

  document.getElementById("display_name").innerText = name;

}

function editform() {
  alert(globalThis.name);
}


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What should happen is when edit is clicked the data entered in the form should be displayed again in the form to edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of removing the form why don't you set its display to none:

```
document.getElementById('heading').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('form').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('display_replacment').style.display = "block";
```

and when you want the get it back reverse

```
 document.getElementById('heading').style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById('form').style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById('display_replacment').style.display = "none";
```

and you can get the name from the `display_name`:

```
const name =document.getElementById("display_name").innerText;
document.getElementById("name").value = name;
```

Comment: I changed the editform() function. The code you gave might work but it refreshes the page when clicked the "edit" button. I changed the code a bit and it shows the input when the clicked "edit" after it refreshes, so it's not possible to display the form details again. Did it work for you?

Comment: you can use session storage